# Not able to fetch the right locator using xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I tried some xpath and showing multiple results. I am expecting to find a locator of 'LinkA' button of color 'Red'. Is there any other xpath that i suppose to use here. Any solution please

this is my code:

```css
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>LinkName</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>
            <button>
                <span>Red</span>
            </button>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>
            <button>
                <span>LinkA</span>
            </button>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>
            <button>
                <span>Yellow</span>
            </button>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>
            <button>
                <span>LinkA</span>
            </button>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>
            <button>
                <span>Green</span>
            </button>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>
            <button>
                <span>LinkA</span>
            </button>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEpoH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
//span[text()='Red']/ancestor::td/following-sibling::td/descendant::button
```

or

```
//span[text()='Red']/ancestor::td/following-sibling::td/descendant::button/span[text()='LinkA']
```

should suffice.

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
///span[text()='Red']/ancestor::td/following-sibling::td/descendant::button/span[text()='LinkA']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have 1/1 matching node, Please make sure that :

1. This div is not under an iframe.
2. This div is not under a shadow-root.
3. You should not be on new tab/windows launched by selenium.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath should work:

```
//td//span[contains(text(),'Red')]]/following-sibling::td//span
```

Literally it finds `td` containing `span` containing `Red` text.
Then if goes to the following sibling `td` containing the desired `LinkA`